# Read file using File mapping not separate line in Edit control

Tags: c++, winapi

I have problem: I use File mapping to read file but it display not separate line in Edit control:

```
szFileName = L"abc.txt";
hFile = CreateFile(szFileName, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE, NULL);
hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(hFile, NULL, PAGE_READONLY, 0, 0, NULL);
pMemory = MapViewOfFile(hMapFile, FILE_MAP_READ, 0,0,0);

int size_needed = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, (LPCCH)pMemory, -1, NULL, 0);
wchar_t *buffer = new wchar_t[size_needed];
MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, (LPCCH)pMemory, -1, buffer, size_needed);

FileSize = GetFileSize(hFile, NULL);
SendMessage(hWndEdit, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)buffer);
delete[] buffer;
UnmapViewOfFile(pMemory);
CloseHandle(hMapFile);
CloseHandle(hFile);
```

My Edit control:

```
hWndEdit = CreateWindowEx(NULL, L"Edit", NULL,
                        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | ES_LEFT | ES_AUTOHSCROLL,
                        50,35,900,300,hWnd,(HMENU)IDC_EDIT,hInstance,NULL);
```

I use UNICODE.

While I debug pMemory and buffer, I see it contain new line character, but in Edit control not display separate line.

Where is error and how to fix !???

Comment: What does SendMessage() return? Maybe the set text call is failing.

Answer (score 4):

The edit control requires a `"\r\n"` sequence (ie character values `0x0D` `0x0A`) to create a new line. You will also need to apply the `ES_MULTILINE` style to the Edit control.

Answer (score 1):

You need reference Edit control style, at here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775464%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

and as you can see, you need to add ES_MULTILINE to your Edit control:

```
hWndEdit = CreateWindowEx(NULL, L"Edit", NULL,
           WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | ES_LEFT | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_MULTILINE, 50,35,900,300,hWnd,(HMENU)IDC_EDIT,hInstance,NULL);
```